# Spring - Startup code with dependency injection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, dependency-injection, javabeans

I'm working on a simple web application using spring-mvc framework.

My configuration only has one single mvc-dispatcher Servlet, (`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`), and all my configuration is in the `META-INF\mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`; I don't have any `application.xml`.

Especially, the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` autowire all my beans.

I would like to execute a piece of code at the startup of my web application, and this code need some beans that I need to inject.

All the examples that I've found advice to implement `WebApplicationInitializer` or `ServletContextListener`. But the problem for me is that both these interface allow to execute my code before the start-up of my main unique Servlet, and therefore, before that my beans are auto-wired.

```
@WebListener
public class MyCustomListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        // I have tried the following to inject the beans:
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(sce.getServletContext());

        WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext())
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(this);

        WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext())
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(this);

        myBean.doStuff(); //NullPointerException
    }


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }
}
```

I've tried to inject my dependencies into the Listener, using something like `WebApplicationContextUtils` or `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`, but my webapplication context is always null; if I'm not mistaken, it's because the FrameworkServlet of spring hasn't read the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and created the webApplicationContext yet:

From `FrameworkServlet.initServletBean`:

```
// this code that create the WebapplicationContext
// is executed after my custom listener
this.webApplicationContext = initWebApplicationContext();
```

What is the standard way to execute code that require beans in my case (i.e. with only a single DispatcherServlet that handle all the configuration)?

**Edit:**

My web.xml is pretty standard:

```
<web-app ... >

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I tried to implement the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`, but the `ContextRefreshedEvent` is never fired when I start my server:

```
@WebListener
public class MyCustomListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> { 

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    // I don't know why this event is never fired?
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        myBean.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Is there a parameter that I should add in my `web.xml` and/or `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` to trigger the event ?

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: A `ServletContextListener` will never work as you only have a `DispatcherServlet` that isn't ready when that component is invoked. Create a bean implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` this event will fire when the context has been loaded and is ready. In the method you need to implement you can do whatever you want.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684451/executing-a-java-class-at-application-startup-using-spring-mvc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring.

Comment: Nicolas, how did you use `@Autowired` in a `@WebListener`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to execute some code after Spring context is initialized. and not before it. You could use `ContextRefreshedEvent` event of the `ApplicationListener`.

> public class CustomInitializerClass implements
>   ApplicationListener{
>
> ```
> public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent ) {
>
> } }
> ```