# How can I execute Database operation at a time of WAR Deployment?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to execute some operation of database at a time of application deployment.

For Front I am using **JSP**, For Back-end **Spring-mvc** and for database operation **Hibernate**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does your application use maven?

Comment: Yes, I am using maven

Comment: By application deployment, do you mean when the application is being built into a distributable package or after the distributable package starts getting deployed by the server?

Comment: What kind of operations? If the operations you need are related to table creation or update, you can have hibernate do them for you. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes) and see if that's applicable to your case.

Comment: I want to call some procedure....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the servlet entry in the web.xml with load-on-startup as 1 which will load during deployment , so you can perform the database operations..
Example

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>MyClass</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyClass</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.controller.MyClass</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyClass</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyClass</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Enjoy bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class which will implement ServletContextListener. Please refer [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1945/servlet-listener-example-servletcontextlistener-httpsessionlistener-and-servletrequestlistener) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746041/spring-injecting-a-dependency-into-a-servletcontextlistener) link. Hope it will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class write your code which you want to execute at time of application deployment and register it with Spring.

Spring will execute it at time of application deployment, as all beans are `Singleton(default)`and are scanned at time of creating Application Context. Moreover you can also implement [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html), if you want to complete some prerequisite before executing the bean code.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684451/executing-a-java-class-at-application-startup-using-spring-mvc