# Is it possible to run something before session is created in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, session

Is there a way that I can run a piece of code before a session is created.  In this situation, I would like to determine whether or not a session has been created for this user or not, and if not do something, and if so, do something else.

//Sudo code.

```
if(session.exists){
     doSomething();
}elseP
     createSession();
     fillSessionWithValuesOnlyOnCreation();
     otherLogic();
}
```

The thing is, Sessions seem to be created before I can make the check to see if the session exists, I've thought aabout checking the creation time and comparing it to current time, but I was curious if there is a better and more reliable way of doing it.  I'm aware of a listener that can be triggered on session creation, but I'm not sure if it will have the request info I 'll need to populate the Session.  And also not sure the order of executions, and if that listener will be triggered before filters execute.

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684451/executing-a-java-class-at-application-startup-using-spring-mvc

Comment: I ended up using the sessionCreated listener and adding a value pair of "new" and true.  So when I go through the logic, I can just see if the session is new, if so doStuff() and set the new value to false.  Thanks for the link, it may help in the future.